# How do I match a string without a specific character in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Which regular expression pattern will match a substring *not* containing a specific character in Python? For example, I have the string `"abc,5 * de"`, and I want to match `"abc"` and `"5 * de"` as two substrings, but not the `,`.

Comment: You could just use `split(',')` for that...

Comment: True for this simple case, but I need to match and replace the substrings within a larger expression.

Comment: If you just want to get substring based on ',', then split would work for large expression also.. Else you can use regex: - [^,]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that contains all characters you don't want to match.

Something like

```
[^,]+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?329m0)

The `[]` denotes the character class and the `^` as first character makes it a negated class.

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "abc,5 * de"
result = s.split(',')
result[0] # "abc"
result[1] # "5* de"
```

Regex expressions are not always the only way to solve string problems.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Python, but with all the regexp engines I know, that would be `/[^,]*/`. Or if Python has a built-in function to split a string on a regexp, then you could just split on `/,/`.